# ScaLapack operation, word and message counts

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, lapack, code-complexity, scalapack

I was wondering if anyone knows any papers or working notes that count how many operations Scalapack routines perform and especially how many messages they send and how many words.

In terms of operation counts I can always browse Golub and Van Loan's excellent Matrix Computations or check Lapack's LAWN 41 and assume they don't change much for ScaLapack, but I cannot find anything on message and word counts and this is a last resort before I go through the code.